# Is there a better way to convert to a specific type with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

Rather than doing what is essentially a large switch statement for every possible type, is there a better more generic way of converting to a specific type with reflection?  I've looked up TypeConverter but don't understand the documentation.

```
if (header.Property.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
{
  header.Property.SetValue(instanceOfTrade, value.ToInt(), null);
}
else if (header.Property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
{
  header.Property.SetValue(instanceOfTrade, value.ToDecimal(), null);
}
else if (header.Property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
{
  header.Property.SetValue(instanceOfTrade, value.TryToDateTime(), null);
}
else
{
  header.Property.SetValue(instanceOfTrade, value.ToString(), null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you mean "with reflection"? Is reflection mandatory approach? Could you post how does your code's consumer look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an extension method (if this is common), or a regular generic method with a "[IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)" constraint on the desired value then call "[Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)" in your SetValue call.

```
static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propertyName, T propertyValue)
        where T : IConvertible
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty( propertyName );
        
        if( pi != null && pi.CanWrite )
        {
            pi.SetValue
            (
                obj,
                Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, pi.PropertyType),
                null
            );
        }
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    TestObject o = new TestObject();
    
    // Propery1 == null, Property2 == 0
    o.SetPropertyValue( "Property1", 1 );
    o.SetPropertyValue( "Property2", "123" );
    // Propery1 == 1, Property2 == 123
}
```

Obviously no error handling and this is assuming you want it available on all types, so I just threw it in an "ObjectExtensions" class so it'll be visible on all types.

Just adjust the constraints to fit your exact needs, or just throw it in a regular class if you don't want to use extensions.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone like me looking at this: I was looking for the line `Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, pi.PropertyType)`